# AngularJS - Combining drag drop with flow chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop, flowchart

Im trying to create a flow chart with drag and drop functionality like[image]

The list of components are dynamic and each component can appear atmost once,
first and last column can have only one component while the all columns between them can have atmost 3 components, there can be n number of these 3 component columns
I've looked into [angularjs-flowchart](https://github.com/codecapers/AngularJS-FlowChart) 
and 
[angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop)
but can't figure a way to combine them, any ideas

Thanks in advance....:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting Project! I believe that SVG and D3.js combined with AngularJS would be perfect for this. d3 can be wrapped into AngularjS directive. It has a lot of cool features that can be tedious to build from scratch. Here is how I would approach the problem.

Have a flow-chart container directive that takes data-model from the main controller. The data-model contains information about each box [by boxes I mean Text 1, Text 2 etc that you have on the diagram]. The flowchart container can then loop through the data-model and for each box create a directive. You can "loop" through the data-model by using something like ng-repeat. Now here is where another directive comes into play. Call it TheBox. TheBox is responsible for drawing the box. You can easily use SVG for this purpose. Also, you can put the d3.js's dragging functionalities in the link function of the TheBox directive.

For more information: 
http://d3js.org/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics

I hope my answer helps you in some way!